# Impedance calculation issue

Tags: impedance-matching, transmission

I am a strange calculation of Zin, Zline and ZL.
As tan(pi/2) is 0, why can't we just cancel the j part, and yield Zin = ZL

but as it demonstrated, using tan(pi/2) to divide, which should not be possible since tan(pi/2) = 0. It Yield Zin = (Zline)^2/ZL.
why is that?

[image]

Comment: tan(pi/2) is equal to infinity and not to zero.

Answer (score 2):

First, \$\tan(\pi/2)\$ equals to \$\infty\$, not to zero.

Second, the math shown in your question is absolutely incorrect. Because you can't just do the following:

$$
\mathrm{
A+j\ B\ C\\
=C \ (\frac{A}{C}+j\ B)
}
$$

when C is \$\infty\$ since \$\frac{\infty}{\infty}\$ is **indefinite**.

Look at the calculation in your question again. The author cancels out \$\tan(\pi/2)\$ on both nominator and denominator by making \$\frac{\infty}{\infty}\$ division hoping this division to give a result of unity. But it does not.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you have is for a quarter wave transformer. The red line in your formulas are wrong. When at pi/2 (90°) the first formula reduces to this: -

$$Z_{IN}=Z_{LINE}\cdot\dfrac{j\cdot Z_{LINE} \tan(90)}{j\cdot Z_{L} \tan(90)}
$$

And clearly the TAN(90°) parts and the "j" parts cancel leaving you with this: -

$$Z_{IN}=\dfrac{Z_{LINE}^2}{Z_{L}}
$$

> *using tan(pi/2) to divide, which should not be possible since
> tan(pi/2) = 0*

No, it isn't zero.